# Is using explicit locks considered expensive?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

It is mentioned that using an explicit lock declaration for object level lock as the one below is a good practice. However, I think for every instance of the object that we create we will end up creating a new object for the lock and access our method via a lock which are both expensive steps.

However, in the case of synchronized method, I believe there isn't any such thing as you are using object's own lock and you only pay the cost of acquiring a lock. You avoid the creation of an explicit lock object.

Am I missing anything here?

```
public class DemoClass
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    public void demoMethod(){
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            //other thread safe code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're really asking here. You create an extra Object per instance of `DemoClass` (unless you're creating millions, so what); you're not creating a new lock every time you invoke `demoMethod`. If you need mutual exclusion, you need something *like* this; so what would be the cheaper alternative?

Comment: At times, you want to perform operations on object state and which needs to be protected from concurrency. Static utility methods may not suffice. I guess the question here is to check if syncronized method would be better than the one I have defined above. With both we can achieve locking.

Comment: `synchronized (lock)` is barely more expensive than `synchronized (this)`. `new Object()` is not considered expensive. Is creating an extra object for each instance of `DemoClass` expensive? It does generate more garbage, but it's not generally considered expensive. Basically, using separate object for locking has a cost, but the cost is not generally considered *expensive*, but it really depends on how many `DemoClass` instances you create. If you are creating millions upon millions of them, then the cost is a factor to consider, otherwise it's not.

Comment: I think since there can be any number of objects that can be created for the DemoClass, there will be no restriction to the number of lock objects we can create.

Comment: @AndyTurner The cheaper alternative is using `synchronized (this)`, i.e. not needing an extra object.

Comment: The difference between this and making `demoMethod` synchronized is that somebody outside this class can synchronize in the instance of `DemoMethod` and hold onto it, blocking the code you want to invoke `demoMethod`; with the code above, only you can synchronize on `lock`, so you know that it can't be held onto in unexpected ways.

Comment: You are talking about a *hypothetical* problem here.  And there is no general advice that we can give that will apply ...

Comment: I am only trying to understand it from a choice point of view. I think we can achieve better with synchornized(this) than using synchronized(lock). It is barely expensive  and I agree. But when this same practice is used across all your codebase and for every object types, it will add to performance cost. I am trying to see what is considered better between the two.

Comment: @TheRoy as a first choice, go for simple, that is, use `synchronized`: if it had totally egregious performance, it wouldn't be there. A private lock gives you more control and flexibility, but in a wide range of cases, you simply don't need that.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thanks. Agree to what you said. I am assuming, you also agree that it is expensive albeit little garbage in using private lock object.

Comment: @TheRoy no. I would echo [StephenC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833372/3788176).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using explicit locks considered expensive?

Generally, no.  It is not considered expensive.  (Modulo that different people have different opinions, and different applications have different requirements.)

The cost of a lock `Object` instance is about 8 bytes of memory plus the memory for the variable holding the reference to the lock in the parent object.  That is 12 or 16 bytes in all.

The cost of creating a lock `Object` instance is ... a few nanoseconds.  (Not exactly sure how many, but it is trivial.)

The cost of reclaiming a lock `Object` instance when it becomes garbage is typically zero.  (The GC costs are incurred when the lock and its parent  object are not garbage ...)

These costs are all insignificant unless you have millions of these objects *or* an excessive object turn-over rate *or* you have severe memory or latency constraints.

(Or if you have decided to put / use locks on things that don't need to be locked.  But that is a different problem.)

There is (AFAIK) minimal difference in the cost of acquiring or releasing a lock on an explicit lock object versus acquiring / releasing the lock on `this`.  Maybe one memory access.

---

For a *typical* application these cost differences won't matter.  There will be more important things to optimize.  The standard advice applies:

- Code it simple<sup>1</sup> to start with.  Simple is easier to write and debug ... and read.
- Avoid optimizing too soon; e.g. while you are writing the code.
- Benchmark and profile your application *before* you optimize.
- Use the results of the measurements to decide what is worth optimizing.

The performance issues probably pale into insignificance compared with the potential problems that can be caused by locking on `this`.  In reality, it depends on your application complexity and implementation details.

---

<sup>1 - Simple enough for you and your co-workers.  It is context dependent.</sup>